# cellForRowAtIndexPath nil during unit tests

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to write a unit test that uses a tableView, and I'm having trouble accessing the cells.

This is always nil:

```
- (void)testDidEndEditingUpdatesLiftRecords {
    TextViewCell *cell = (TextViewCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

Despite the fact that I set the data source in the setup

```
- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    source = [[MyDataSource alloc] init];
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    [tableView setDataSource:source];
```

What could be

Comment: have you set the delegates to your table view?

Comment: Can you show the code you wrote for the delegates?

Comment: Is there any content on your tableView or it is a blank one ?

Comment: As amit3117 hinted at, you still have to, minimally, set "numberOfRowsInSection" and "cellForRowAtIndexPath".

Comment: The datasource defines the number of rows, and cellForRowAtIndexPath and tableView: .... are both defined.

Comment: There's no tableview delegate. I don't need one. The data renders fine when I run the actual app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instantiate an actual `UITableViewController` and this works fine.

Comment: Not sure how this answer helps.

Answer (score 8):

As posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832276/tests-for-custom-uitableviewcell-cellforrowatindexpath-crashes-with-nil-outlets/41554931#41554931) (Swift 3) I had to call the cellForRow the datasource cellForRowAt function instead of accessing straight from the tableView.cellForRow function

```
//this 
let cell = controller.tableView(controller.tableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))

//instead of this
let cell = controller.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
```

Answer (score 5):

As the docs say, the `UITableView` method [`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath%3a) returns "an object representing a cell of the table or `nil` if the cell is not visible or `indexPath` is out of range." Thus, if the cell is not currently visible on a tableview, this method will return `nil`.

Note, this method should not be confused with the [`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW6) method that we implement in our [`UITableViewDataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). The names are confusingly similar.

Comment: FWIW, you should ask yourself whether you unit test UIKit controls, like table views, at all. This is the domain of UI tests. See [Testing Your App in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/testing-your-apps-in-xcode). Things like table views are covered in UI tests, not unit tests. Unit tests are for business logic and the like, usually encompassed in non-UIKit, objects, e.g., in view-models, presenters, etc.