# Tests for custom UITableViewCell, cellForRowAtIndexPath crashes with nil outlets

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a ViewController that contains a tableView. Since I need to keep the code well covered with tests, I need to write a test for [tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath]

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var source = [
        Country(name: "USA", capital: "Washington, D.C."),
        Country(name: "Argentina", capital: "Buenos Aires"),
        Country(name: "Mexico", capital: "Mexico, D.F.")
    ]
    let cellIdentifier = NSStringFromClass(MainViewController.self)

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: "MainViewController", bundle: nil)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView?.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return source.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? CustomCell
        if let cell = cell {
            cell.countryLabel.text = source[indexPath.row].name
            cell.capitalLabel.text = source[indexPath.row].capital
            return cell
        }
        return CustomCell()
    }
}

struct Country {
    var name: String
    var capital: String
}
```

The tests look like the following:

```
import UIKit
import XCTest

class MainViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    var controller: MainViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        controller = MainViewController()
        controller.view.description
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testTableViewOutlet() {
        XCTAssertNotNil(controller.tableView)
    }

    func testTableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath() {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

        let cell = controller.tableView(controller.tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        XCTAssertEqual(cell.countryLabel.text!, "USA")
        XCTAssertEqual(cell.capitalLabel.text!, "Washington, D.C.")
    }
}
```

I get the following error when running the tests:

```
Test Case '-[CustomTableViewCellTests.MainViewControllerTests testTableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath]' started.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This function has alluded tests for months in my production application since [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier] returns nil only when run from the tests. I have actually tried many different approaches I have read in StackOverflow, like:

1. Creating the CustomCell when [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier] returns nil
2. Loading the NIB for the CustomCell using a temporaryController and grabbing the view, which is supposed to be connected to the cell

The bottom line is that I get close to a solution, I create an CustomCell object, but the outlets for the cell remain nil. I haven't found the piece of code that would realize the outlets into initialized elements so I can make my tests pass.

I am including a basic iOS project with its own git which contains the code that I have included here. It is a UIViewController that contains UITableView which displays data using a custom UITableViewCell. I'm hoping a find a solution that realizes the custom cell with its outlets to make the test pass.

Git repo source: 
    https://bitbucket.org/jallauca/customcell/src

To clone the git repo:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/jallauca/customcell.git
```

Comment: Whenever you're posing a question about an error or crash, please also include any log message that explains the crash and perhaps the relevant portion of a stack trace.

Comment: My web browser warns me that your links point to a possible phishing site. Please post the relevant code directly rather than asking people to view it somewhere else.

Comment: My first guess is that the view is not loaded. Just instantiating the controller from the xib/storyboard doesn't load the whole view or connect all outlets. Accessing the view property might do the job, although testing this way leaves many question open - as many behaviors might be just undefined and don't make sense, like querying UI state for elements that have never been part of the view tree.

Comment: http://bitbucket.org is a free hosted site just like http://github.com. Since iOS apps make code and xib files relevant to troubleshoot, it is easier to clone the project or just look at the source if it answers a question.

Comment: Questions on SO are meant to be useful for future readers, not just for the person originally asking the question. Links break all the time, so it's important to include the code in the question. Your original link included your user ID, and that causes some browsers to warn about phishing. I edited the question to correct the link such that the problem is avoided, but it's still important to include the code in the question.

Answer (score 4):

For me, (Swift 3) I had to call the cellForRow datasource cellForRowAt function instead of accessing straight from the tableView.cellForRow function

```
//this 
let cell = controller.tableView(controller.tableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))

//instead of this
let cell = controller.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that could be going wrong here. Some possibilities:

1. `tableView` itself could be nil.
2. No cell prototype in the nib or storyboard with the reuse identifier in question.
3. You haven't registered a cell class with the reuse identifier in question.
4. Cell allocation fails for some other reason, such as lack of memory.
5. Some class, such as the table cell class, not included in the test target. (This would usually cause a build error rather than a crash.)
6. Cell's .xib file not included in the test target.
7. Relevant objects in .xib aren't connected to the proper outlets.
8. Your crash is happening because you're trying to allocate a new cell in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. That used to be necessary if no cells were available for reuse, but these days a properly configured table will instantiate new cells as needed, and IIRC instantiating your own can cause a crash.

Comment: I have included the two main source files for developers who like to see the code inside the forum. 1. tableView is not nil as the test now shows. 2. I don't use storyboard, but xib, but I register the cell class in the viewDidLoad. Must I also do it in the xib? 3. I did register the class as shown now in the code. 4. I can discard lack of memory in this case. 5. All classes are included in the test target, I double-checked. 6. Same as 5.

Comment: I'm glad you can point what's wrong with the code. Can you please provide with the steps I need to do to fix it? Specifically, "Relevant objects in .xib aren't connected to the proper outlets". What am I missing?

Comment: That's just a possible problem. I haven't checked your .xib to verify that objects are connected to their outlets. You should be able to do that yourself. If you find that they are not connected to their outlets, then connect them! Think of the list above as items to check, not things that are definitely wrong with your code.

Comment: I've verified that the outlets are connected properly. When the app runs, the tableview, the cell and its respective outlets are displaying all data properly. When the tests run, the tableview outlet is connected but the cell or its outlets don't materialize into objects. Download the code if you can, you would really see that whatever is missing is not obvious. I've browsed through all of StackOverflow but although solutions were related, nothing necessarily had to do with unit tests.

Comment: @JaimeAllauca, have you managed to find a solution for you problem? Currently I am experiencing a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate concepts, the tableView and the dataSource. TableView is just a view, and has cells which are views as well. DataSource is the data provider of the tableView, and the only component responsible for data.
In your test example, you call a `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath` function in order to get a cell, in a specific indexPath. Based on official docs, ***this function will return nil if the cell is not visible***. So this function should be used, only when you know that the table is visible.
In your example, you are trying to test that your table will load data properly. When referring to data, data source is the first thing that should come to your mind. So you need to test that the dataSource will bind the correct information to your cells. As a result you call `controller.tableView.dataSource(controller.tableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)))`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Go to Identity Inspector of your view controller in storyboard and give it a storyboard id. Ex: "vcIdentifier"

Step 2: You have get the instance of your storyboard in Unit test

Step 2 : Instantiate your view controller via storyboard instance from step 2

Step 3 : Get access to your table view from the viewcontroller and pass it to 'cellForRowAt' method in your test. Please see below a sample code:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let newsViewController: UITableViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "vcIdentifier")
    return newsViewController.tableView
```